# Reference signal minimizes the MSE across similar signals with delays

Tags: cross-correlation, optimization

I am dealing with the following problem:

I have $M$ signals ($x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_M$), each of length $N$, which are supposed to be similar, up to a certain delay between them and noise. I am searching for a reference signal $s$ that minimizes the mean squared error (MSE) across all of them, considering delays. In other words:

$$
s=\text{argmin}∑_m∑_n(x_m[n+d_m]-s[n])^2 
$$

where $d_m$ can be an integer between $0$ and $N-1$ and depending on the signal $m$.

I am attempting to find the best signal, not an approximation. I've tried to solve the problem, and even though I've obtained various interesting intermediate results, I haven't been able to find a solution. Additionally, I searched online for articles or books discussing this topic, but I wasn't successful. Does anyone have a reference / idea to a source that could help?

I've encountered a similar question previously:
[How to estimate ALL time-delays across MULTIPLE signals?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48007/how-to-estimate-all-time-delays-across-multiple-signals)

However, the provided answers do not guarantee minimal MSE. For instance, adopting an approach of selecting a reference signal (e.g., $x_1$), aligning all the other signals with it, and then calculating their average could be a promising strategy. Yet, I haven't come across a proof demonstrating that this approach minimizes the MSE.
I have managed to establish that this problem is equivalent to minimizing the MSE between the signals, defined as follows:
$$
MSE(x_1,x_2,…,x_M)=∑_m∑_k∑_n(x_m[n+d_m]-x_k[n+d_k])^2 
$$
Hence, if someone knows how to tackle this problem it will be great.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to select a reference signal, else the delays $d_m$ are undetermined. A signal delay is always relative to some other signal.
2. Say $x_r$ is your reference. Given the supposed similarity of the signals, the delay $d_m$ between $x_m$ and $x_r$ is given by the maximum of the cross-correlation:$$ d_m=\text{argmax}\left(R_{x_rx_m}(k)\right)$$
3. Alining the two signals employing said $d_m$ will minimize the difference between them, given a decent $\text{SNR}$. If the signals are too noisy, there is no analytical method to find the guaranteed minimum, so we have to presume this.
4. So, by aligning regarding each $d_m$, we minimize each summand of your formula for a given reference signal. This leaves in question the choice of the optimal reference signal. We have to take a look at the similarity between the signals. There is nothing we can do about the noise, so we ignore it for the moment. Any signal $x_m$ can be modeled as $$x_m = g_m\cdot x_r + e_{\text{nl}}$$
   with $g_m$ as a gain factor and $e_{\text{nl}}$ as any error resulting from nonlinear distortion. We just add the nonlinear part to the noise and thus ignore it. That leaves the gain. Now there is two ways to tackle that. Either you could disregard the gain by normalizing all signals to any one signal, then the choice of reference signal would not matter, or you choose your reference so that the MSE is minimized regarding the gain by choosing the reference signal with the gain closest to the mean gain: $$m_r = \text{argmin}\left(|g_m-g_\phi|\right)$$ with  $$g_\phi=\frac{1}{M}\sum_1^Mg_m$$
5. Regarding the noise: I ignored it, because nothing can be done about it. However, at least we can estimate its impact on the actual value of MSE. Say it is stationary white noise with a level of $l$. Further, lets say all signals are equal except the noise part. This leaves only noise in the summation. Summing up $M$ uncorrelated noise signals of the same level will yield an increased RMS level by factor $\sqrt{M}$. MSE calculation has no square root, so this becomes $M$. But each summand already had the noise increased by factor $\sqrt{2}$ for RMS, $2$ for MSE, yielding an overall lower boundary for the MSE of $2Ml$.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the prompt response.

You wrote, "If the signals are too noisy, there is no analytical method to find the guaranteed minimum, so we have to make this assumption." Do you know if it is an NP-hard problem? I am not opposed to using an approximation algorithm, but I want to start by establishing that the theoretical problem is NP-hard.

Thank you!

Comment: If the SNR is very low (say $<6\text{dB}$), the problem can be tackled only algorithmically. It comes down to calculating the energy of every possible difference signal for every possible reference signal. In big O notation, this gives something like $\mathcal{O}(M^2N)$, so it's doable in polynomial time. That said, it does not neccessarily make sense, as the difference signals will all be in the very close neighborhood of $3\text{dB}$ above the original noise level.

Comment: Do you know if it is an NP-hard problem?

Comment: Sorry, my theoretical IT class is 15 years past, never had to deal with NP-Hardness again.